# edit the config.yml file in the controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

For some security reasons each customer have his own database in my Symfony 3.4 application
here an exemple of my config.yml file:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_pgsql
                host:     127.0.0.1
                port:     null
                dbname:   default
                user:     user
                password: password
                charset:  UTF8
            customer1:
                driver:   pdo_pgsql
                host:     127.0.0.1
                port:     null
                dbname:   customer1
                user:     user
                password: password
                charset:  UTF8
            customer2:
                driver:   pdo_pgsql
                host:     127.0.0.1
                port:     null
                dbname:   customer2
                user:     user
                password: password
                charset:  UTF8
```

and ORM :

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    BackBundle:  ~
                    BackBundle: ~
            customer1:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: false
                connection: customer1
                mappings:
                    BackBundle: ~
            customer2:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: false
                connection: customer2
                mappings:
                    BackBundle: ~
```

I can get the config.yml file with

```
$value = Yaml::parseFile('/pathtofile/app/config/config.yml');
```

the $value contain an array but even when I use array_push() the result is unreadable

My questions :

First I want to create a new database connection in doctrine and a new orm configuration in the config.yml file automaticly when the admin create a new user 
after I want to execute `doctrine:database:create --connection=dbname` and `doctrine:schema:update --force --em=emname`
all this in the controller without editing manually the config.yml file

Thanks

Comment: This is bullshit. I am sorry. But HOW is this nightmare helping security? It won't work at all due to the architecture the config is passed into the container dumping process. In other words: Every config.yml change needs a full cache wipe. This shows HOW wrong you current approach is.

Comment: I am asking a question and I am waiting for an answer not a thing like bullshit
this is the needs of the company so please if you have an answer write it else I don't need your judgment

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to replace the actuel config.yml by a new generated file.

Like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$value = Yaml::parseFile('/pathtofile/app/config/config.yml');
$value["database_host"] = "10.2.2.1"

file_put_contents('/pathtofile/app/config/config.yml', $value);
```

[Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html)

Comment: `Warning: Array to string conversion` - This does not work!